# How to dynamically add script which will be executed right now?

Tags: javascript

There is the simple page:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/x.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      console.log($);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

'scripts.x.js':

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js';
script.async = false;
script.defer = false;
document.currentScript.parentNode.insertBefore(script, document.currentScript.nextSibling);
```

This script just adds a new external script tag right after current script, but it doesn't work, because 'console.log' writes error 'index.html:8 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined'. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: As you can see I'm trying to add JQuery dynamically @RayonDabre

Comment: Well in that case, some other part of your JS is being executed before `jQ` is loaded...

Comment: I understand it, but why? 'scripts/x' add JQ right after himself, before 'console.log'

Comment: Because, `script` is being added `asynchronously`..use `promise`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that because of the asynchronous I/O model of JavaScript the script doesn't do what you expect. You probably think the script will stop executing while jQuery is loading, then continue once the external script (`https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js` in your case) is loaded.

What actually happens is that the I/O operation is done by another thread and by the time the JS interpreter reaches the `console.log` call, the I/O hasn't finished yet and therefore `$` hasn't been initialized yet.

I suggest that you try `requirejs` - it handles loading of external scripts asynchronously.

Comment: is it possible to do it without requirejs